# binding a click event on a directive's child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

more angular confusion. namely, why cannot i bind a child element of a directive to a click event?

```
app.directive('expandingTile', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                console.log('elem hit!');
            });
            elem.find('div#CloseBtn').bind('click', function() {
                console.log('found child hit!')
            });
        }
    }   
}]);
```

Comment: Check the return value of elem.find and see if it is actually finding anything? You might have to show some html or css. Could it be z-index related, or style related somehow else?

Comment: If you are using jqLite then find will only find elements by name. So searching by id as you are here will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this

```js
link: function (scope, element) {
    $timeout(function () {
        element.on('click', '#Id', function () {
            console.log('inside event handler of the first child)
        })
    })
}
```

And Don't forget to inject $timeout in directive

Comment: Error: [jqLite:onargs] jqLite#on() does not support the `selector` or `eventData` parameters